# Visible box in \ChoiceMenu

Tags: hyperref

I am trying to make a fillable Form with  the hyperref package. The form will be used both in PDF- and in printed form, so I would like the box from \ChoiceMenu to be usable in PDF, and visible when printed out. Meaning the box that could be checked is black when printed, but can be checked in the PDF as well. I use the \ChoiceMenu in the following way:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{hyperref}   

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\textbf{Choice }\\
\ChoiceMenu[name=choice,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{54}]{\mbox{}}\ Option A \\
\ChoiceMenu[name=choice,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{54}]{\mbox{}}\ Option B \\
\ChoiceMenu[name=choice,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{54}]{\mbox{}}\ Option C \\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```